# How to trigger function with parameter upon event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am aware of the following three ways to set up an onclick event in javascript:

```
<element onclick="myScript">
object.onclick=function(){myScript};
object.addEventListener("click", myScript);
```

But when I try to do the following it doesn't work:

```
 object.addEventListener("click", myScript("value"));
```

How can I achive the desired result most elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

`javascript` at Question calls `myScript` immediately. You can use `Function.prototype.bind()` to reference `myScript` and pass parameter `"value"` to `myScript` when invoked at `click` of `object`

```js
function myScript(val) {
  console.log(val)
}

var object = document.querySelector("button");
object.addEventListener("click", myScript.bind(object, "value"));
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```